# CMake compile with external library

Tags: c++, cmake

I try to compile my code with an external library but every time I tried I've got an error. Here is my actual cmake linkage:

```
include(dependencies.cmake)
add_executable(${NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${NAME} PUBLIC ${DEPENDENCIES})
```

And here is my dependencies.cmake:

```
set(LIB_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
find_library(MY_DEPENDENCIES NAMES myLib HINTS ${LIB_PATH} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
set(DEPENDENCIES ${MY_DEPENDENCIES})
```

And here is my project tree:

```
Project
|----include
|----lib
|    |----libmyLib.so
|----release
|----src
|----CMakeLists.txt
|----dependencies.cmake
```

And I've got this error

```
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '../lib/libmyLib.so'
```

I precise that:

- I work on Ubuntu with CMake 3.9.3
- I use a shadow build in release to build my project.
- I do not want to use directly the sources of my lib or to install it in /usr/lib.

Anyone as a suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to reconfigure your project with empty build directory or with `CMakeCache.txt` file removed from it? Looks like you have changed the project's layout since `find_library` has been executed the first time.

Comment: Please do not append [Solved] to your question title. If an answer solved your question, simply mark it solved by clicking the green arrow next to the answer. If you found the answer on your own, you can simply answer your own question. Please see the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I find what causes the error, my external lib was a symbolic link and not the .so directly, I fix this and now it work